# After compiling a C# console/terminal program in Visual Studio, how do I run the program outside of VS?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, build, executable

I wrote a C# terminal/console app in VS, it compiled and built fine, below are the files I can see in the project folder.

[image]

How do I turn those files into the mac equivalent of an EXE file?

Answer (score 0):

What you have created there is a component. Not an executable program. You probably selected the wrong project type. You should have selected a Console App as the project type.

Comment: I did create a console app. Further research has shown me that VS does not create a mac executable. I'm trying to learn how to do that. The next step is what I need.